Why is type conversion (uint8->float32) of a large tensor slower with pytorch than with opencv in C++?
I'm working with a large tensor (1200x1900x3) in PyTorch C++ and performing a type conversion from uint8 to float32. I’ve noticed that this conversion is quite a bit slower with PyTorch compared to the same operation using OpenCV. Here's a sample of my code:
#include <chrono>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <torch/torch.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat frame = cv::Mat::zeros(1200, 1920, CV_8UC3);

    //OpenCV conversion
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    cv::Mat float_frame = cv::Mat::zeros(1200, 1920, CV_32FC3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        frame.convertTo(float_frame, CV_32F);
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Conversion to float 32 with opencv: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count()/1000.0 << "ms" << std::endl;
    

    //Pytorch conversion
    torch::Tensor tensor = torch::from_blob(frame.data, {frame.rows, frame.cols, 3}, torch::kUInt8);
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    torch::Tensor float_tensor = torch::empty({frame.rows, frame.cols, 3}, torch::kFloat32);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        float_tensor = tensor.to(torch::kFloat32);
    }
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Conversion to float 32 with pytorch: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count()/1000.0 << "ms" << std::endl;

    //Pythorch conversion with CUDA
    torch::Tensor tensor_cuda = tensor.to(torch::TensorOptions().device(torch::kCUDA).dtype(torch::kUInt8));
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    torch::Tensor float_tensor_cuda = torch::empty({frame.rows, frame.cols, 3}, torch::TensorOptions().device(torch::kCUDA).dtype(torch::kFloat32));
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        float_tensor_cuda = tensor_cuda.to(torch::kFloat32);
    }
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Conversion to float 32 with pytorch and CUDA: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count()/1000.0 << "ms" << std::endl;
}

The output when running this is:
Conversion to float 32 with opencv: 2.402 ms
Conversion to float 32 with pytorch: 3.034 ms
Conversion to float 32 with pytorch and CUDA: 0.01 ms

I have also tested the same thing in Python and it's way faster than both of the cases in C++:
import torch
import time

tensor = torch.randint(0, 256, (1200, 1920), dtype=torch.uint8)

start = time.time()
for _ in range(1000):
    img = tensor.to(torch.float)
end = time.time()
print("Time to convert to float: ", (end - start), "ms")

Output:
Time to convert to float:  1.2969393730163574 ms

Questions

Why is there a 25% performance difference between opencv and pytorch when converting on the CPU in C++?
Does pytorch allocate a new tensor every time .to is called, while opencv doesn't? If yes, do these memory allocation really take that much time?
Why is the conversion in Python 2x faster than doing the same thing in C++?
Is 3-4 ms still reasonable for such a simple operation as converting 8 bit integers to 32 bit floats?


Any comparison should be done with a release build and optimizations enabled.  Also do NOT use high_resolution_clock but std::chrono::steady_clock. (high_resolution_clock may map onto system_clock which is not monotonic). Also test on much much larger datasets (to exclude constant time overhead). All in all performance testing cannot be done naively, in the end you would need a profiler to really know where the bottlenecks really are.
